# Importing Published status from xml using Xpath parser

Tags: feeds

I have an xml page that I want to import. Although I'm able to successfully import the Title and Body, Im unable to import the published status and promoted-to-front-page settings for the page.
Here is what my xml code looks like:

```
<nodes>
<node>
<Title>This is the Title
</Title>
<Body>
This is the Body
</Body>
<Order>1</Order>
<Path>
/clips/this-is-the-path
</Path>
<Post-date>Tuesday, February 17, 2015 - 09:33</Post-date>
<Promoted-to-front-page>No</Promoted-to-front-page>
<Published>Yes</Published>
</node>
</nodes>
```

Here are what my Xpath settings look like:
[image: Xpath Settings Screenshot]

Could anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, After some search online, I was able to use the innate Xpath functions, so it works with the following expressions:
[image: Screenshot of the xpath expressions]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest installing feeds tamper (https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) with this module you can easily convert the yes to a 1 and no to a 0 before saving to the database. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, The only reason I didn't use feeds_tamper was because it was not recommended by few community members online. I have +1'd your post!

Comment: Oké thanks a lot, do you have more information on why they wouldn't recommend using it? I used it in the past and I loved it, it also made it easy to create my own custom functionality on how to deal with data before saving to the database.